# prof for limit of a sequence by definition

Tags: real-analysis, limits

if $x_n=\frac{1}{ln(n+1)}, n \in \mathbb{N}$,   I want to show that $\lim (x_n)=0$

Given  any $\epsilon>0$, we should show that exist $n_0 \in \mathbb{N}$ such that the inequality $|\frac{1}{ln(n+1)}|<\epsilon$ holds.

$|\frac{1}{ln(1+n)}|<\epsilon \Rightarrow ln(n+1)>\frac{1}{\epsilon} \Rightarrow n+1>e^{\frac{1}{e}}  \Rightarrow n>e^{\frac{1}{e}}-1$.

Therefore, if $n>e^{\frac{1}{e}}-1 \Rightarrow |\frac{1}{ln(n+1)}|<\epsilon \Rightarrow \lim (x_n)=0$

Is everything correct?

Comment: Perfect, your approach is correct

Comment: I think you might need to replace the $\Rightarrow$ s by double arrows. Thee way you have it now you're assuming what you want to show and then going back from there.